# Linq between class of table database and List<T>

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a list of information that I keep in the session. Want a LINQ to join this this list and a table of the database.

The result is coming reset, nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Class of List:

```
public class ASOProcedimentoTemp
{
    public int FuncionarioID { get; set; }
    public int ProcedimentoID { get; set; }
}
```

Class of table database:

```
public class ASOProcedimento : IEntidadeBase
{
    [Key]
    public int ASOProcedimentoID { get; set; }
    public int ASOID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ASOID")]
    public virtual ASO ASO { get; set; }
    public int ProcedimentoID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProcedimentoID")]
    public virtual Procedimento Procedimento { get; set; }
    public DateTime DtProcedimento { get; set; }
}
```

My LINQ:

```
var dadosTemp = HttpContext.Current.Session["ASOProcedimentoTemp"] as List<ASOProcedimentoTemp>;
if (dadosTemp == null)
    dadosTemp = new List<ASOProcedimentoTemp>();

result =
    (from a in dados.AsQueryable()
        join b in dadosTemp on a.ProcedimentoID equals b.ProcedimentoID
        select new 
        {
        a.ProcedimentoID,
        a.Procedimento.Descricao
        })
    .Where(where, filtro)
    .OrderBy(orderna + " " + ordenaTipo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Contains will cause a SQL Where In clause with your IDs in your sql call.

```
var dadosTemp = HttpContext.Current.Session["ASOProcedimentoTemp"] as List<ASOProcedimentoTemp>;
if (dadosTemp == null)
    dadosTemp = new List<ASOProcedimentoTemp>();

var procedimentoIDs = dadosTemp.Select(a => a.ProcedimentoID).ToList();

result =
    (from a in dados
        where procedimentoIDs.Contains(a.ProcedimentoID)
        select new 
        {
        a.ProcedimentoID,
        a.Procedimento.Descricao
        });
```